# What makes PC SDRAM so much more expensive than the same capacity in a chip?

Tags: memory, ram, sdram, ddr3

I'm picking a SDRAM IC for a custom embedded board and was surprised by the low prices. Was expecting orders of magnitude similar to PC ram of the same capacity.

For example [H5TC8G63AMR-PBA](https://www.olimex.com/Products/Components/IC/H5TC8G63AMR-PBA/) chip costs almost 4 times less than this [Corsair Vengeance 8GB (1x8GB) DDR3 1600 MHz (PC3 12800)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005T63BJM).

Digging into the [datasheet](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwjH_dTsp7_QAhWLfRoKHfjlAf4QFgghMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.skhynix.com%2Fproduct%2Ffiledata%2FfileDownload.do%3Fseq%3D2414&usg=AFQjCNEZ045rZwKfzrYCzIcP5KpiXYK6UQ&bvm=bv.139782543,d.d2s&cad=rja) [page 4] for the RAM on chip it states that it its configuration is 512M x 16 and the speed isn't clear from the name.

- Is the speed the main reason for the difference?
- Are there other factors (like a need for a PCB) that multiply the price?

Comment: Are you comparing one chip with a DDR stick that contains eight of the same chip?

Comment: Have you calculated how much of the chips you need for the same capacity? Plus the PCB? Plus manufacturers need to make money?

Comment: @pjc50 The reference for the chip states `DDR3 8Gbit 512MBx16 0-70C`. From that I've assumed the 8Gbit is the capacity of the chip.

Comment: @Alan Correct, 8 Gbit. Which means you need 8 of them to get 8 GBytes of memory.

Comment: @Andrew So it should be `512Mbx16` instead of `512MBx16`?

Comment: Also in terms of speed that part can do PC1600 with timings of 11-11-11, one clock slower than the DIMM you linked to. So you are getting a slower part for twice the price.

Comment: @Andrew `that part can do PC1600 with timings of 11-11-11` can you please explain how you got this?

Comment: @Alan Yes. And it doesn't say 512MBx16, that is meaningless. It says 512M x 16, 512M addresses, each one 16 bits wide.

Comment: @Alan, page 4 of the datasheet that you linked to. Operating frequency for a -PB part.

Comment: @Andrew `And it doesn't say 512MBx16, that is meaningless`: Sorry, that was on the distributors site, should of referenced the data sheet.  `page 4 of the datasheet that you linked to`: Wouldn't it need the additional parameter in the name (`CL`) for unambiguous frequency reference?

Comment: @Alan CL is short for CAS Latency, (CAS in turn is short for Column Address Strobe, this is an abbreviation of an abbreviation).  This is a parameter determined by the memory controller not the memory chip, it is up to the board designer what the value is. So if you clock it at 800MHz you can use a CAS latency of 6 clock cycles, if you use a higher clock you need to allow more cycles of CAS latency.

Comment: In this case, the chip is actually a dual die package, and there is probably a cost to that too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To put the comments into the form of an answer so that the question can get closed...

The SDRAM part linked to is a 512Mx16 device, 512M addresses, 16 bits wide giving a total of 8Gbits.

The DIMM linked has a capacity of 8GBytes, 8 times the capacity of the individual memory chip.

The DIMM also lists its speed as PC1600 with timings of 10-10-10. For the memory chip the -PBA at the end indicates that it is PC1600 with timings of 11-11-11 (the PB) in a x16 configuration (the A).

So while the DIMM is 4 times the price you are getting 8 times the memory that can run 10% faster.

Comment: And the length-matched impedance-controlled properly-terminated board for free ;)